# active record performance; $this->db chained or repetitive

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm writing a lot of queries in codeigniter. I use Active Record and I can do:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('example');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

or

```
return $this-db->select('*')
->from('example')
->get()
->result_array()
```

I find the bottom one more readable, but I was wondering if the eventual SQL query and/or the performance are affected by the way of writing the AR queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speed should be about the same with both as PHP will just compile the SQL for you when you use Active Record.

The easiest way to check this would be to include `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` in the constructor (or method) of your controller which will show you exactly how long the different queries (and more) took.

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks. Since I'm not running very big and/or complex queries this answers my question.